# How do I set path for ag for helm-do-grep-ag

Tags: exec-path, ag, helm-grep, mac

I am on MacOS (darwin) and when I attempt `helm-do-grep-ag` I get a zsh error `zsh:1: command not found: ag`. What is the proper way to address this?

My ag is homebrewed and so is in /usr/local/bin

I verified the setting of PATH in both bash and zsh startup, and if I open a shell inside emacs I see /usr/local/bin there. (pasted from emacs shell session:)

```
echo $PATH
/Users/cgrandi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I then also tried adding it to the `exec-path` variable:

```
Its value is
("/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin")
```

I note that variable is defined in 'C source code' and so I suspect it does not influence commands executed from 'helm-grep.el'

As a workaround I customize the variable `helm-grep-ag-command` to include the explicit full path

```
Its value is
"/usr/local/bin/ag --line-numbers -S --color --nogroup %s %s %s"
Original value was 
"ag --line-numbers -S --color --nogroup %s %s %s"
```

But I suspect that is not the proper way to do it.  Is this in fact the best way to address that?  Or is there a more proper way?

Comment: Looks like you need [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)

Comment: @Mathletics exec-path-from-shell appears to have worked.  I'm a little disappointed that one needs to install a package to get emacs to work "properly" on a mac, but maybe that's the way it is.  I don't know if it's the best solution, but I like it much better than my workaround.  I cannot credit you (other than comment +1) because you have only commented and not answered.

Comment: I think my original confusion was compounded by the fact that running `echo $PATH` from an emacs shell (i.e. in a buffer obtained from running emacs `shell` command) may yield different results than `(getenv "PATH")` especially on a Mac.

Comment: Added as an answer! I originally didn't answer because I assumed this would get closed as a dupe, but searching around I don't actually see a good replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a standard case for [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

Essentially, the emacs environment is dependent on where it was started from (e.g. GUI app vs terminal vs daemon, etc.) This package loads your real shell and copies the values into emacs.